# Getting XML to display in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I've been messing with some script online to parse out an XML to display it in a table. Unfortunately, unlike in the examples I've seen around, mine isn't displaying a table.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","europe.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 

    document.write("<table border='1'>");

    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("country");

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        document.write("<tr><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("users")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td></tr>");
    }

    document.write("</table>");
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is europe.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<continent name="Europe">
    <country>
        <name>Albania</name>
        <users>1.6 Million</users>
    </country>
    <country>
        <name>Austria</name>
        <users>6.7 Million</users>
    </country>
    <country>
        <name>Belgium</name>
        <users>8.6 Million</users>
    </country>
</continent>
```

Comment: Any reason why XSLT isn't being used to transform the XML into XHTML?

Comment: As @DaveJarvis mentioned above, if your intention is not to load the XML as *part of an existing HTML document*, but transform the entire XML into HTML, XSLT is definitely the best option. You could try it out and ask a question tagged with XSLT if you have any trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to generate the table in a string and then append the generated HTML to an existing element using DOM.

1) Add a container to your HTML where you wish to place the table:

```
<html><body>
...
    <div id="container"></div>
...
</body></html>
```

2) Load the XML file:

```
var client;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    client = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    client = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
client.open('GET', 'europe.xml');
```

3) Read the file contents. This should be done *inside an Ajax callback function*, to assure that the file is read before processing begins. Normally you would test the response code, etc.Here is an example:

```
client.onreadystatechange = function() { // will run when the file loads
    // get the response XML
    var xmlDoc = client.responseXML;

    // get the list of countries
    var countries = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("country");

    ... // the rest of the code (see below)
}

client.send(); // this will send the request which will be captured by the function above
```

4) Get the list of `<country>` elements (this is in the code above):

```
var countries = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("country");
```

5) Get the container `div` where the table will be added:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
```

6) Create an HTML table in a string and put the element data inside it:

```
var tableString = "<table border='1'>"; // Make a table and put the element data inside it
for (i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    tableString += "<tr><td>";
    tableString += countries[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    tableString +="</td><td>";
    tableString += countries[i].getElementsByTagName("users")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    tableString += "</td></tr>";
}
tableString += "</table>";
```

7) Append the table to the container:

```
container.innerHTML = tableString;
```

This example uses pure JavaScript. You might also want to try a solution using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) which will probably reduce the lines of code above to about half.

See http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/N2nER/ for an example (I used an embedded XML instead of Ajax in the fiddle, to avoid loading an external file)

**UPDATE**: Here's the entire HTML page, in case you have trouble assembling the parts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script>

        var client;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            client = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            client = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        client.open('GET', 'europe.xml');

        client.onreadystatechange = function() { // will run when the file loads
            // get the response XML
            var xmlDoc = client.responseXML;

            // get the list of countries
            var countries = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("country");

            // get the container where you want to embed the table
            var container = document.getElementById("container");

            var tableString = "<table border='1'>"; // Make a table and put the element data inside it
            for (i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
                tableString += "<tr><td>";
                tableString += countries[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                tableString +="</td><td>";
                tableString += countries[i].getElementsByTagName("users")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                tableString += "</td></tr>";
            }
            tableString += "</table>";

            // append the table to the container
            container.innerHTML = tableString;
        }

        client.send();

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1></h1>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome walk-through! Unfortunately, it's not working. I think it might have to do with the external file. I'll play around.

Comment: Actually it might have to do with the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. The way you are loading the file is actually not 100% OK as I wrote up there, since the file might not be loaded by the time the code is executed. I can help you fix that in a few minutes.

Comment: I changed the question a bit and pasted a full HTML document that should load your XML correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much! Still only works in Firefox, but I take your word that this is how it's done. I can follow to code and see what it does. This can only be a learning experience.

Comment: I ran it on Chrome and Safari and t worked. I didn't test it in Windows or tablets. In Web Design you always have to deal with browser incompatibilities, but there are frameworks such as JQuery that help with that. If you write a new question (linking this one as a reference) asking for a JQuery solution, you might get some good browser-independent solutions, since JQuery takes care of browser incompatibilities.

Comment: @user3362954 - if you think it's awesome then at least give him an upvote! There's a lot of work went into it. And if it solved your problem, then accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/xemop/3/edit)**

```
// Just a reusable function. See use below.
function nodeVal(el, tag) {
  return el.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest?
  new XMLHttpRequest():
  new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); /*IE*/

// AJAX is asyncronous, so wait for a response
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4) { // Good to go!
    var XML,
        TXT = this.responseText; // Get the XML string

    if (window.DOMParser){       // Parse
      XML = new DOMParser().parseFromString(TXT,"text/xml");
    }else {                      // IE
      XML = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
      XML.async = false;
      XML.loadXML(TXT);
    }

    // Get desired elements from XML
    var el  = XML.getElementsByTagName("country");

    // Loop elements and retrieve data
    var html = "<table border='1'>";    // Ok, actually a string :)
    for(var i=0; i<el.length; i++){     // concatenate our string
      html += "<tr><td>"+ nodeVal(el[i], "name") +"</td>"+
                  "<td>"+ nodeVal(el[i],"users") +"</td></tr>";
    }
    html += "</table>";

    // Finally append our html String
    document.body.innerHTML = html;
  }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "europe.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

tested also in IE7